# Positive continuous functions on closed intervals always greater than epsilon?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to show that if we have a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)>0$ on it's entire domain, then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)\geq\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

I've figured that f being continuous on a closed interval means it's uniformly continuous, and this must have something to do with it, because I can think of functions such as $e^x$ which if defined from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ do not satisfy this condition (since it's not uniformly continuous).

I'm struggling with the rigour and how to write this up in particular - any ideas please?

Comment: Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: Can it be done without using the Extreme Value Theorem? We haven't covered this yet so am not sure about it

Comment: You could do it from scratch, but that would most likely mean reinventing a proof of the EVT, more or less.

Comment: As an aside, I was wondering if continuity is necessary: so as an example I constructed $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x $ for $x \ne 0$; $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: but $\inf (f)=0$

Comment: @stu $inf(f) =  0 $ ?

Comment: $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists x_0\in(0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)<\varepsilon$

Comment: @stu That's the wrong way round. For any $\epsilon > 0$ then for $x \in (0, \epsilon )$ we have $f(x) < \epsilon $. So there is no $\epsilon > 0 $ with $f(x) \ge \epsilon$ on $[0, 1]$

Comment: @TomCollinge, Ok, I understood, you thought your example sastified the definition.  I was wrong. Sorry

Comment: @stu - no problem - any easy mistake to make (done it myself) - let's keep these comments here, someone else could find them useful.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is no such $\epsilon$. Then for every $n \geq 1$ we can find $x_n \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n) < 1/n$. The sequence $x_n$ is bounded and hence by Bolzano-Weierstrass has a convergent subsequence $y_n$, whose limit $y$ lies in $[a,b]$ since $[a,b]$ is closed. Then by continuity of $f$:

$$ f(y) = f(\lim _{n\to \infty}y_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(y_n) = 0 \,,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! Since you used the fact that the limit of the subsequence lies in [a,b], this wouldn't work if the domain was the reals right?

Comment: Both $\mathbb{R}$ and $[a,b]$ are closed, so that's not the important distinguishing feature. What's relevant is that $[a,b]$ is *bounded*, which allows us to conclude that there is a convergent subsequence in the first place. We couldn't do this if the domain was $\mathbb{R}$. Exercise: what goes wrong in the proof if the domain is $(a,b)$?

Comment: If the domain is (a,b) we can't conclude that the limit of the convergent subsequence lies in (a,b) right? cause it could be a or b themselves?

Comment: Yes, that's right.